# how to correctly improve mongodb(pymongo) query wih createIndex?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, pymongo

we have a collection that has over millions records
and i want to find the best way to improve querying in this collection
i searched a lot and found a way to say use to createIndex in that field most used for query
and i make createIndex in field that name user_id like this:

```
db.logs.createIndex({'user_id':1})
```

but there was no change in the speed of querying
and every time i query, my usage of Ram is going too high, something like 12GB usage of ram
and i don't know what is for,
how exactly can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure each doc has the field `user_id` in exactly that case?  Unlike SQL, MongoDB fields and queries are case-sensitive.  Next:  Let's assume you have a `user_id` value of `A1` that you wish to find.  Execute `db.logs.find({'user_id':'A1'}).explain(true)` and post the results here.

Comment: Please post some details like: a sample document, the query you are trying and having problems with, and finally, any indexes you have created on this collection. These details can help others understand what might be the problem.